# Uniform distribution on pairs of unitary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, random-matrices, haar-measure, inner-product

This question has two parts.

In Part 1, I would like to know if the following distribution on pairs of $d$-dimensional unitary matrices has popped up in the literature:

"Uniform distribution on pairs of unitary matrices with a fixed inner product"

In other words, I am trying to understand the distribution where pairs of unitary matrices are chosen at random such that their inner product remains fixed, and each choice of matrices is equally likely.

Has this distribution been studied in the random matrix theory literature? Does it have a name? Is there an efficient process (with respect to dimension $d$) to sample from this distribution?

One can think of a vector analog of this distribution: Uniform distribution on pairs of unit vectors with a fixed inner product. Do we know more about this vector analog?

For Part 2, imagine $X,Y$ are two unitary matrices with inner product $\alpha$. Consider the distribution over pairs of matrices $(U X V^* ,U Y V^* )$ where $U,V$ are unitary matrices sampled independently from the Haar measure. Of course if $(A,B)$ is a sample from this distribution, then $TR(A^* B) = TR(X^* Y) = \alpha$. In this sense, this distribution seems at least somewhat like the distribution in the first part. But additionally, here if $(A,B)$ is any sample then $A^* B$ is unitarily similar to $X^* Y$ and $A B^* $ is unitarily similar to $X Y^* $.

So the question is how close is this distribution to the distribution in the first part?